How can I import a stylesheet from another workbook?
I get the following error message:
The stylesheet "D:\OneDrive\Documents\Mathematics\Physics\E&M\ElectroDynamics_v3.0.0\9_Relativistic_Electrodynamics-working-stylesheet.nb" depends upon a stylesheet named "ElectroDynamicsRegistrationStyles.nb" which cannot be found by the Wolfram System.

Please edit the question and include more details. Where did you get this notebook from? When and where does this error message show up? Do you have access to ElectroDynamicsRegistrationStyles.nb?

I found the associated file from the previous Mathematica version. From .../Mathematica/Applications/ElectrodynamicsRegistration/StyleSheets
It was a Mathematica note book. I used the stylesheet editor and used that notebook to import styles.

Which previous version precisely?

I found the associated file from the previous Mathematica version. From .../Mathematica/Applications/ElectrodynamicsRegistration/StyleSheets
It was a Mathematica note book. I used the stylesheet editor and used that notebook to import styles.
